# How to use $interval for continuous polling in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my Angular code, I have a code for long polling, that looks like this

```
var request = function() { 
    $http.post(url).then(function(res) {
        var shouldStop = handleData(res);
        if (!shouldStop()) {
            request()
        }
     };
}
request();
```

The function gets called immediately after the page load.

However, now I am trying to set up testing in Protractor and I got this error message

> Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see 
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. The following tasks were pending:

In the [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md), I read the following:

> Before performing any action, Protractor asks Angular to wait until the page is synchronized. This means that all timeouts and http requests are finished. If your application continuously polls $timeout or $http, it will never be registered as completely loaded. You should use the $interval service (interval.js) for anything that polls continuously (introduced in Angular 1.2rc3).

How should I edit my code to use `$interval`? I thought that interval is an angular wrapper for `window.setInterval`, I am not sure how to use that for long polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the `$interval` thing in the docs belongs to the `$timeout`, not to the `$http`.

Well, I will just throw away Angular's `$http` and will just use `fetch` (with additional `$rootScope.$apply` and JSON deserialization) to do the same thing

Comment: you may want to look at socket io for long polling.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server is not something that we can change to websocket right now